# How to quickly view data inside gnucash file?

Tags: gnucash

Gnucash loads for about 40 seconds (on my device). It's not handy to load it, watch one number and close it.

How to generate data from it (e.g. export everything in plaintext form to console) fast, without booting that GUI?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to save GnuCash database on MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite, so you can make any SQL statement to collect data as you wish, without loading GnuCash.

Comment: Then how to make GnuCash use sqlite instead of `~/gnucash/gnucash` xml file?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the sqlite drivers, you can save your postgres as an sqlite database. The schema is not particularly friendly, but you might be able to figure out the SQL you need to generate a report.

IMO, you want reporting to be **informative** and **actionable.** If those two criteria aren't met, it's just going to be a waste of time. What will you do differently by tracking your portfolio's net worth?